# Bootstrap kills my media query code

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's my `@media` query code:

```css
@media (max-width:1200px) { 
    html { background-color: red; } 
}
```

This code works, but only UNTIL I add the Bootstrap CSS.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

When I add bootstrap, my `@media` query stops working.

Comment: in what order are you declaring your styles vs the bootstrap css? if your styles are declared first, bootstrap may be overriding them (if bootstrap sets `html { background-color: /*some other color*/; }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bootstrap sets (the equivalent of):

```css
body {
    background-color: white;
}
```

So you can probably just change your selector to `body` without any problems:

```css
@media (max-width:1200px) { 
    body {
        background-color: red;
    } 
}
```